# What is "cook-house yarn "cook-house yarn "?

Tags: meaning

> ‘But he spoke as though my Eirene were a fig-basket. “Oh, she’s bound
>   to go ashore, somewhere,” he said, “but not a life will be lost. Take
>   this from me, the Servant of the One God.” Mad! Mad as a magician on
>   market-day!’
>
> ‘No,’ said Sulinor. ‘Madmen see smooth harbours and full meals. I have
>   had to — soothe that sort.’
>
> ‘After all,’ said Quabil, ‘he was only saying what had been in my head
>   for a long time. I had no way to judge our drift, but we likely might
>   hit something somewhere. Then he went away to spread his **cook-house
>   yarn** among the crew. It did no harm, or I should have stopped him.’

This is from "The Manner of Men" by Kipling.
https://ebooks.adelaide.edu.au/k/kipling/rudyard/limits/chapter19.html

I do not understand the meaning  of "cook-house yarn "

I am glad if some one would kindly teach me.

Comment: [*yarn*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/yarn): "*countable noun* - A yarn is a story that someone tells, often a true story with invented details which make it more interesting. " Related to a cook-house somehow.

Answer (score 1):

I expect this is an idiom which would have been common in Kipling's day, or at least in his peer group.   It's also possible that it's a direct translation from an idiom in another language.

In any case, as user3169 mentions, a *yarn* is a kind of exaggerated story, full of incredible and often unbelievable details, which the listener is supposed to believe to be true.

> Late that night around the campfire the old sailor **spun a yarn** about the time he was save from a giant sea monster by a mermaid.  The children were completely taken in, while the rest of us (who had heard the tale before) laughed quietly in the shadows.

Note the idiomatic "spin a yarn" meaning "tell a tale".  Other words for yarn:  *tall tale, whopper, (old) chestnut, fish story* and various others.

I'm just guessing, but I expect a "*cook-house*" yarn references the kind of exaggerated stories told by cooks to young, gullible children, the kitchen being a common place to exchange stories and gossip in certain communities.

Be aware that even thought it was not published that long ago, Kipling's English sounds stylized and archaic (not to mention more than a little racist) to many modern English speakers, and includes so many esoteric idioms (*"quarter-hatch", "brailed", "a handy driver aft", "get up your girt-hawsers"*) that even well-read native speakers will spend a lot of time guessing what he's talking about.  These idioms may be entertaining, but they'll only cause confusion if you try to use them in conversation.

Comment: Andrew， thank you so much for your kind and detailed answer! I have understood the meaning so well.